# Namespace mixed up by Compilator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Sometimes there are two places with partly identical namespaces, like

> Project.Data.Anything.ClassName
>   Project.Business.Anything.ClassName

It's common that the Visual Studio refers to the other namespace. This is a little out of logic when it occurs with "using Project.Data.Anything;" in the header.

This means that If i write

```
public void ClassName
```

It links to the business version. Most often i just ignore it and print the whole namespace but in a few projects (specifically this one) it's going to be hard to read and very much overhead.

Any ideas, someone?

Comment: Perhaps remove the reference from References section of your project in Solution Explorer as well.

Comment: Half year ago and I hardly remember the problem and why it was :). The problem was that my former developer created a DAL and BL with same namespace path namings (execpt a Data indtead of Businesd. This leaded to reference problems only when DAL and it's BL was referenced in same class. The answer below was the nearest possible solution.  Or not repeat the namings in each layer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define namespace

```
using Business = Project.Business.Anything.ClassName;
```

and then use shorter namespace

```
Business.ClassName
```

Comment: Thank's, but i wouldnt up-vote that. Because it does not solve or describe my actual problem.. I won't (i.e.) use namespace in every object use in methods/classes where the reference is obvious.. (i'm open if i'm wrong on something here).

Comment: can you show code snippet what you have and what you want to get

Comment: See my two first lines in the question. If i write just the classname ClassName (without full ns), the compiler will still refer to Business part, even if it's removed from the using part (namespace does of course still exist). That's spooky.. It has to bee something in this project since long time (developer before me) because there are so many places with full ns. Completely useless and hard to read!